# JVM bytecode line number

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, memory-address

We are trying to analyze Java code with only bytecode.

Is there a way to either let JVM spit out the addresses of bytecode it is executing or intercept the addresses of the bytecode issued to JVM at runtime ?

According to the crash stack, it seems that JVM should have all that information.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what do you mean by "spit out the addresses of bytecode"?

Comment: Of course, there is. It’s called “debugging API” and you may find it, if you really search for it…

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. We are trying to do source code coverage analysis.  So we want to see whether there is a way to ask JVM to report the line numbers of the Java source code.  If JVM cannot, then is there a way to ask JVM to report the line numbers of the executed bytecode.  Thanks

Comment: @FarnWang It is possible (although I'm not sure how) - you may want to check existing code coverage tools such as cobertura or jacoco...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are open source code coverage tools available and what these do is used instrumentation of the code to track which lines have been executed.

The JVM executes native machine code, rather than byte code at runtime.  You need  to use code injection to add instructions to what ever you need between byte code instructions but this will slow down the execution. If you just need to see if a line is executed ever you can set a flag for each line once which should be quicker.